# DOS command to execute all SQL script in a directory and subdirectories

Tags: sql, t-sql, batch-file, dos

I need a DOS command or a batch (.bat) file I can execute to run all the *.sql scripts in a directory and its subdirectories. What would the solution be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will get you started

```
for /r %f in (*.sql) do echo %f
```

Run from the command line that will print the names of all the SQL files in the current directory and all sub directories.

Then substitute `sqlcmd <connection args> -i%f` for `echo %f` to execute the scripts.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A down vote with no comment? How can this be? Seriously, if you don't like my answer, or there's something wrong with it can you let me know? We're all here to learn.

Comment: Try to use directories and file names without spaces. (it may be handy http://www.den4b.com/?x=downloads&product=renamer)

Answer (score 3):

```
for %f in ("c:\path\to\dir\*.sql") do sqlcmd -S [SERVER_NAME] -d [DATABASE_NAME] -i "%f" -b
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go. This batch file will execute all sql files in a directory and its subdirectories.  It will also create an output.txt file with the results so you can see errors and whatnot.  Some notes on batch file:

- [YourDatabase] is the name of the database you want to execute the scripts against.
- [YourPath] is the path of where you keep all the scripts.
- [YourServerName\YourInstanceName] is the SQL server name and instance name, separated with a '\'
- You'll want to replace the text after the '=' for each variable with whatever is appropriate for your server
- Be sure NOT to put spaces around the '='
- Do not put any quotes around [YourPath]
- Make sure that [YourPath] has a '\' at the end

  SET Database=[YourDatabase]

  SET ScriptsPath=[YourPath]

  SET ServerInstance=[YourServerName\YourInstanceName]

  IF EXIST "%ScriptsPath%output.txt" del "%ScriptsPath%output.txt"

  type NUL > "%ScriptsPath%output.txt"

  FOR /R "%ScriptsPath%" %%G IN (*.sql) DO (

  sqlcmd -d %Database% -S %ServerInstance% -i "%%G" -o "%%G.txt"

  echo ..................................................................................... >> "%ScriptsPath%output.txt"

  echo Executing: "%%G" >> "%ScriptsPath%output.txt"

  echo ..................................................................................... >> "%ScriptsPath%output.txt"

  copy "%ScriptsPath%output.txt"+"%%G.txt" "%ScriptsPath%output.txt"

  del "%%G.txt"

  )

Comment: Adding the following line after the `SET`s ensures that there is a trailing backslash: `IF NOT %ScriptsPath:~-1% == "\" SET ScriptsPath=%ScriptsPath%\`

Answer (score 0):

Try a `for` loop. The options of this command have evolved and I'm not sure what version of DOS you are using, but assuming that DOS includes "`cmd.exe` from Windows XP", something like this could work:

```
for /r . %f in (*.sql) do @echo %f
```

Ok, this will only print the names of the files. I'm assuming you already have a program that you can run from the command line that will execute *one* SQL file, which you can use instead of `echo`.

For more information, try `for /?`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET Host=pmegat
SET Database=pdb
SET user=usr
SET pwd=abc123
SET ScriptsPath=C:\Work\Scripts

IF EXIST "%ScriptsPath%output.sql" del "%ScriptsPath%output.sql"

echo SPOOL Script.log >> "%ScriptsPath%output.sql"

FOR /R "%ScriptsPath%" %%G IN (*.sql) DO (

echo Prompt execute @"%%G" >> "%ScriptsPath%output.sql"
echo @"%%G" >> "%ScriptsPath%output.sql"

)
echo SPOOL OFF >> "%ScriptsPath%output.sql"
echo exit >> "%ScriptsPath%output.sql"

sqlplus %user%/%pwd%@%Host%:1521/%Database% @"%ScriptsPath%output.sql"
```